# Twitter Substring Searches

Tags: api, search, twitter

If there is a way to do this, it should be a fairly straightforward question. Using the twitter search api, is there a way to return results that contain a part of the word (searching "#dog" would return "#dogs" as-well)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. What you can do is search for "#dog OR #dogs" and that will return results for both.